# How do you start from a snapshot in android studio?

Tags: android-studio

I understand Eclipse has a "launch from snapshot" option, but where is the equivalent in Android Studio?  I see an option to save to "store a snapshot for faster startup" but not to start from one. The emulator is clearly starting up and slowly.. rather than just going straight in via a snapshot.

Comment: Googling showed this http://tools.android.com/_/rsrc/1296669915186/recent/emulatorsnapshots/20110121%20avd%20use%20snapshot.png but I don't have that I think that pic might be an old version of android studio

Comment: Well, it really looks like an **Eclipse** screenshot! :) In facts, my **Eclipse** emulators have that option.

Comment: @DerGolem Thanks, i've fixed my question.. looking for the equivalent in android studio.

Comment: I think think the feature, despite being enableable, is absent from Android Studio. I've filed an issue for it: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=181054

Comment: @Sam  there is an update at that link.. it looks like they don't understand the problem / they can't see how to reproduce it!    I haven't used android studio for ages as I haven't programmed mobile devices for a while.. If you use it, and are still interested in the problem, then perhaps you could update that  code.google.com thread?

Comment: I gave up on getting them to fix it. :) I think their last comment on that thread is just a generic template, but the reason the issue is closed is `Won't Fix (Infeasible)`, which I take to mean `It's not worth our time`.